# How to add 1 minute to each value in a vector in R Studio?

Tags: r, vector, time, posixct

I am currently using a vector to extract certain rows from my data set based off time (formatted as POSIXct):

```
Vector.Time   <- c('2020-03-06 10:09:11', 
                   '2020-03-06 10:13:11',
                   '2020-03-06 10:18:12')
```

One of the instruments I am using logs data at the end of each minute, so I need to reference a second vector where 1-minute is added to all the values in the original vector. Is there a simple way of doing this without having to create a new vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `minutes` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
as.POSIXct(Vector.Time) + minutes(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add/subtract time for `POSIXct` object using base R, it is done by second. So to add 1 minute in `Vector.Time` you can add 60 seconds.

```
as.POSIXct(Vector.Time) + 60
```